# Removing large gap below collapsible when expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a html table which is hidden in a collapsible. My problem is when the collapsible is expanded there is a large gap underneath the table. I can't figure out why.

Please find pictures and demo below. Thanks for your help

Collapsible Opened

[image: Collapsible Opened]

Collapsible Closed

[image: Collapsible Closed]

DEMO:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible{
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapsible:before {
  content: '▶';
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 13px;
}
.collapsible.active:before {
  content: "▼";
}
.content {
  padding: 0 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3 id="Accounts">&nbsp;Fiat Accounts</h3></button>
 <div class="content" id="acc_list">
  <table class="acc_table" id="acc_table">
    <tr id=acc_row1>
      <td id="acc_name1" class="accname">Cash</td>
      <td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54<button class="edit_account" id="editaccounts">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=acc_row2>
      <td id="acc_name2" class="accname">Credit Card</td>
      <td id=acc_balance2 class="accbal">$1362.21<button class="edit_account" id="editaccounts">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=acc_row3>
      <td id="acc_name3" class="accname">Checking Account</td>
      <td id=acc_balance3 class="accbal">$4322.50<button class="edit_account" id="editaccounts">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=acc_row4>
      <td id="acc_name4" class="accname">Savings Account</td>
      <td id=acc_balance4 class="accbal">$12322.50<button class="edit_account" id="editaccounts">✎</button></td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have used the developer tools (in Chrome: ````F12````), to inspect if a default (````tr````, ````td````) element has a margin?

Comment: Are you sure that the `.scrollHeight`-property is correct? did you compare the height of the table with and without the script? And you set max-height to null in javascript but initial max-height (from css) is 0, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @michaelT I checked and there was nothing wrong with the margins of tr and td. It turned out I had used tbody somewhere else, so I think it used that.

Comment: Please provide enough code, so that your issue is **reproducible**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking developer mode I found the issue was .tbody{height}. Thanks for the tips!